# mbed EventQueue call

Tags: mbed

I'm trying to make an EventQueue call inside a method attached to a Ticker. The EventQueue, and context thread is declared within the class which holds the method in question. A simplified example:

```
    class EventHandler
    {
    public:

    EventHandler() {

      t.set_priority(osPriorityRealtime);
      t.start(callback(&queue, &EventQueue::dispatch_forever));

    }

    void handler() {

    //Do whatever

    queue.call(&exobj, &ExampleObject::update, 0x0); //call update within user context, with state exobj, and parameter 0x0

    }

    private:

    ExampleObject exobj;
    Thread t;
    EventQueue queue;
}
```

Main File:

```
int main() {
    EventHandler eventhandler;
    Ticker tick;
    tick.attach(&eventhandler, EventHandler::handler, 1); //call handle periodically
}
```

On compilation, the following error is displayed:

```
Error: Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type in "extras/mbed-os.lib/events/EventQueue.h", Line: 2883, Col: 14
```

Can anyone explain this? I have followed the correct syntax for making calls on the EventQueue

Comment: Did you forget to close the `}` at the end of your `class EventHandler`, or is that a copy-paste bug?

Comment: @brhans, I literally wrote this in the question, just to demonstrate what the actual code is doing. So yeah, may as well be a copy-paste bug :)

Comment: ... and is the 3rd line in your `main()` missing an **r** at the end of `EventHandler::handle`?

Comment: Yes, let me update the question.